# Travel on low cost airlines

Tags: air-travel, schengen, low-cost-carriers, freedom-of-movement

I've touristic Schengen visa and I need to know is possible to travel on low cost airlines like Raynair between different EU countries and cities?

Comment: It is worth pointing out that Ryanair has an additional passport check before the security controls for non-EU citizens.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible! Schengen visa allows you to travel inside Schengen area by foot, boat, car, air and even more

Comment: Not all EU countries are Schengen members.

Comment: I know you can move freely inside Schengen aria but do I've the right to use low cost airy

Comment: Yes why not? There is no restriction on who can use low or regular costs airlines in Europe.

Comment: @Chlebta Yes, you can. Ryanair will [check your documents](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/54014/3221) and you can fly wherever you wish in Schengen area.

Comment: You might not be able to check in online for some airlines, Ryanair has/used to have that restriction and might not be the only one. And check-in at the airport is more expensive.

Comment: And not all Schengen countries are part of the EU.

Comment: I'll add that it's important to truly compare prices. A low-cost carrier may not be cheaper once you factor in baggage fees, check-in fees, seat selection fees, rebooking fees because you missed your connection and the airline doesn't guarantee connecting flights, fee for paying a fee fees, etc...