# Should I cancel my existing Schengen visa in order to get a new one with a few more days of validity?

Tags: schengen, italy

I have a current Schengen visa from France valid from 15-4-2016 till 15-7-2016 and have a trip in summer to Italy and France from 7-7-2016 till 15-7-2016 which is the last day of my visa validity.
I prefer to not take this risk and return on the last day (flights delays or cancellations or other situations...)

So I was thinking if I can have a new visa from Italian consulate which will be certainly given to me for some extra days after my intented return.
The France consulate told me I can cancel my visa without prejudice to ask for a new visa from italian embassy.

The question is: will the Italian embassy accept it?? Especially that my actual visa cover all my stay in summer but I only want to eliminate any risk for returning on the last day.

Comment: You should be fine. If your flight is delayed, you can always wait in the transit area. You will already have been stamped out.

Comment: Yes, there is always a chance the the Italian Embassy will not grant your visa, causing your whole trip to be jeopardized. As Michael Hampton writes, since it is your plan to return on 15-7 anyway, just get stamped out then. As long as you have done so and are in the transit zone, you're good to go as far as leaving on time.

Comment: The biggest issue is that I will have an internal Schengen flight from Italy to France with Ryanair and they ask in their policy to check the visa... In the day of this flight the will be 4 days remaining in my visa. Do they have the right to deny me boarding due to this remaining period? Are there any requirements about the visa remaining validity to fly auch as having 3 months left in the passport?

Answer (score 2):

> The biggest issue is that I will have an internal Schengen flight from
>   Italy to France with Ryanair and they ask in their policy to check the
>   visa... In the day of this flight the will be 4 days remaining in my
>   visa. Do they have the right to deny me boarding due to this remaining
>   period?

There are no visa checks on intra-shenghen flights. I am not sure what they would be checking for anyway - travel between Schengen member states is visa-free (that's the whole point of the entire Schengen framework).

However, even if Ryanair checks your visa - it is valid till midnight of the date stamped. They should not deny you boarding.

Comment: [Ryanair famously conducts visa checks for unknown reasons on intra-Schengen flights](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54014/why-does-ryanair-check-non-eu-passengers-visas-on-intra-schengen-and-domestic-f)

Comment: I contacted Ryanair and have been told that the visa is not under ther control to check it... so what do they check it for the non EU? And that I should ask passport controlers!! And of course there is no passport control between 2 Schengen states! I am confused since they asked for this requirement...

Answer (score 0):

As stated by an Italian visa section manager at VFS:

- In order to change days on your visa, you need to cancel your current visa and re-apply for a new one.
- They wanted to see my itinerary covering **all days of stay in Schengen**. So to apply for a longer period, you may need to revise your itinerary.
- In principle, Italian authorities can extend the visa, which, however, is not guaranteed. From other sources, the extension is only granted in "exceptional cases".