# Does Wizz Air have a passport check for non-EU citizens on Schengen flights?

Tags: schengen, passports, wizz-air

I've flown on Wizz Air from Schengen to UK and remember there was a mandatory passport check for non-EU citizens, which had to be done at the check-in desk.

Is there also a mandatory passport check on Schengen and internal flights?

The question is important for planning tight connections on two bookings.

(See the related Ryanair question [Flying with Ryanair as a non-EU citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53994/9009) for what these kinds of passport checks look like.)

Comment: Did they not check the documents of EU citizens? How did they know they wereEU citizens without checking their documents? More importantly, how would the UK know they were EU citizens if they didn't have documents?

Comment: @phoog EU citizens are checked at the gate. Non-EU citizens (at least for UK flights) are checked at the check-in desk. See the related Ryanair question for more details on this low-cost policy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Wizzair website](https://wizzair.com/en-GB/useful_information/web_check-in#show) states (under "Online check-in" -> "Conditions"):

> Non EU/EEA passengers must proceed to the Wizz Air check-in desk for
>   document check before proceeding through security to departure.
>   Failure to do so may result in travel being denied.

No exception is mentioned for intra-Schengen flights.

Answer (score 4):

From my recent experience flying as a non-EU citizen with WizzAir from and to Schengen Area, **documents check is required only when entering the Schengen Area**.
When flying outwards, I made a couple attempts and each time was told that no check needs to be done.