# Is this an erroneous statement in Wizz Air's online check-in form?

Tags: schengen, passports, check-in, wizz-air

When performing online check-in for a Wizz Air flight, I was asked to read and confirm the following statement:

> If you are an EU/EEA citizen, please go to Wizz Air’s check-in desk
>   for a document check before proceeding through security to departure.
>   Failing to do so may result in your travel being denied.

I have sent a complaint using the online form informing Wizz Air of this problem. However, I will most likely not receive an answer as per the email I got from them:

> Thank you for your message sent to our Customer Relations Department.
>
> Please note that no reply will be sent to your enquiry apart from this
>   automatic message but if you have general questions, we have many of
>   the answers to the most frequently asked questions available on our
>   website.

Comment: Thanks @Fiksdal. Likely, there will be no definitive answer from Wizzair. (See the updated question description)

Comment: Yes, it was. Of course :)

Comment: I have included a link to this question in my complaint. With any luck, we might get an answer from Wizzair right here.

Comment: That would be very good. They'd have to somehow prove they are official Wizzair staff, though.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this statement is erroneous?

Comment: @NateEldredge read Fiksdal's answer. The requirement is most likely directed at *non-* EU/EEA travelers, and they most likely have omitted a "not" from their text. I agree that the question would be clearer if it made this explicit.

Answer (score 9):

It seems quite likely that this is a mistake in Wizzair's wording. Indeed, they make [pretty much the opposite statement here](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/booking-information/check-in-and-boarding#show):

> If you hold non-EU travel documents, you need to present yourself at
>   the check-in counter to have your documentation checked and your
>   boarding card stamped.

Credit goes to [ptityeti's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/77054/41775) to another question for leading me to that source.

So, these two quotes are contradictory. One says **EU/EEA** citizens have to present themselves at the check-in desk to provide their documents, the other one says **non-EU** citizens have to do so. If we were to take both these quotes as accurate, the conclusion would be that **everybody** has to do it. In that case, they obviously wouldn't have to mention EU/EEA at all, they could just state plainly that **all passengers** have to do it.

Therefore, it seems to me that they have made a mistake in the text you are quoting in the OP, and they meant to say basically the same thing as what is quoted in this answer. However, when official sources contradict themselves in this manner, it is certainly recommended to contact them directly to ask for clarification. You have already done this. As you have suggested you will, please do share the response with us.

#### However, I would just go there anyway

If you don't get a response from Wizzair, I would just go to the check-in desk regardless. The company has been utterly unclear regarding this. And, since they have now said officially in writing that you **are** required to go to the check-in desk (and may be denied boarding if you don't), I would just do it. It may take 20 minutes, but it's better than risking being denied boarding, IMO. Yeah, it's probably very unlikely that they would deny you boarding, but in the unlikely event that they did it might be legal for them. After all, they *did* tell you in writing to go to the check-in desk. At the check-in desk you can also get a clarification from the staff there, and then post that clarification as an answer here on TSE. :)

<sup>Side note: Technically, it could be possible that it's in fact the quote quoted in *this answer* that is inaccurate, but that would make much less sense. Why would EU/EEA passengers be subject to *more* scrutiny on Wizzair's flights when the vast majority of [Wizzair's destinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizz_Air_destinations) are within the EU/EEA? And why would *all* other nationalities *not* be subject to the rule? It would seem like a bizarre practice. Again though, you might want to ask Wizzair directly.</sup>

Comment: As a general principle, if one is uncertain whether it's necessary to do something to comply with some legal or practical requirement, the safer course of action is to do it anyway. As the saying goes, it's better to be safe than sorry: if it's not necessary, they'll just tell you so.

Comment: And if everyone goes to the check-in desk, it might lead them to change the wording sooner rather than later!

Answer (score 6):

[image: I think that clears all the doubts]
@wizzair already commented on the issue back in September.
But they still have not changed it in the text showing on online check-in.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it depends on the context, and that anyway the message it's entirely correct.

Standard Wizzair's check-in procedure is explicit in that the check-in counters **must** be visited for non-EU travels document; it goes on details by stating that you have to do that for document checking and for boarding cards stamping.

What you are reporting, instead, is really a lot different: it is given to you as an advice ("*please* go" + "Failing to do so *may result*"), not as mandatory ("*need*") and it just says that you should go so that they can check for you if your documents are ok for the upcoming flight.

They are suggesting you to use their check-in counter service (paying for that - Wizzair's check-in counters are not free) so to be sure to not have problems later, and as they warned you of this chance whatever happens next it's not their fault.

Finally, while as an EU/EEA citizen you are free to travel whithin Schengen area, if by chance you take a Wizzair flight to a place outside EU, the above statement holds even more strenght: "You are an EU citizen and took a Wizzair flight to UAE: are you sure that your documents are ok for your destination? Come and let us check them for you and provide you [paid] assistance"

Comment: Are you sure WizzAir charges for document checks or such inquiries at the counter (if you already checked-in online)?

Comment: We are speaking about Wizzair, here; there is nothing to be sure about when it comes to them :-D