# Mobile boarding for Ryanair for non-EU citizens?

Tags: schengen, tickets, ryanair

I am traveling back to Italy tomorrow but I forgot to print the boarding pass (I do have the PDF on my phone). I wanted to confirm whether I really needed to print it before going to the airport and that I cannot just use my phone. I have seen the other questions related to this but they seem to be very old.

Comment: Worst case scenario, Ryanair will want to charge you a fee for printing a boarding pass when you arrive.

Comment: You can try changing your nationality to an EU one, using the mobile boarding pass and then sorting things out at the gate if necessary. Haven't tried it myself yet, but seen some reports of this working.

Comment: @JonathanReez I think you'd run into issues with that because Ryanair [requires](https://www.ryanair.com/us/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/passports-and-visas/im-a-non-eu-eea-passenger-do-I-need-extra-travel-document-visa-check) non-EU passengers have their travel documents checked and their boarding pass stamped at a special check-in counter, and I've heard tales of people missing their flight because they skipped that step and didn't have time to go out of the secure area and have it done and come back. No personal experience though.

Comment: @ZachLipton apparently this is no longer the case, even though Ryanair still states it in their policies: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/81576/9009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I printed the boarding pass to be safe but still used the pdf on my phone to pass through all of the checkpoints. It does say that on Ryanair's website but at the airport in Budapest (to Milan, Italy), there was no need to show them the printed pass.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my personal experience: you cannot use pdf on your phone. But if you checked-in, chances are good that Ryanair won't charge you for printing your boarding pass. But don't do it at check-in counter, go to the Ryanair information counter.

Another option: you can try to print your boarding pass in a copy-shop at the airport if there are any.

Comment: In my experience there is not always a difference between check-in and information counters for Ryanair.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't trust them with a 10 foot pole.  I have the boarding pass on my Ryanair mobile app, but I am an American citizen with residency in Spain and have a residency card which may not be enough for money grubbing Ryanair which threatens to charge 55 Euros or 55 pounds (around the price of my round trip!) to print out a boarding pass (much more than the much hated Spirit Airlines in the States).

I am printing off the boarding pass but will try the mobile app first and see what happens.  This really sux because who has a printer nowadays?  Everyone does everything with their mobile.  If this airline were not so freaking cheap and did not go where I want to go, l would be willing to pay more and not be subject to their numerous indignities.

Comment: I never used Ryanair, (because it does not use my nearest airport among other reasons,) but I have found KLM to be on par with EasyJet on routes both fly and found Ryanair not cheaper than BA for a UK to Italy trip (looked up for a friend.)

Answer (score 0):

Ryanair will not accept a PDF of your boarding pass on a phone, and are notorious for charging a lot of money for printing boarding passes at the airport.

However even if you have already printed a boarding pass you can still use Ryanair's [new mobile boarding pass app](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Mobile-boarding-passes/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ryanair-s-mobile-boarding-pass).

The link takes you to a page where you can select Apple, or Android/Google Play to download.

Comment: [The mobile boarding pass is not available for non-EU citizens.](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Mobile-boarding-passes/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ryanair-s-mobile-boarding-pass) Since OP needed to specify their passport during the online-check-in, in my understanding they are not even able to use the mobile boarding pass on the app.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Air does not allow non-EU citizens to print a boarding pass.  Even its own employees don't know this.  I was on line with a Ryan Air rep today who said I should have no problem printing my boarding pass and avoid the 20 Euros charge.  There is no escape.  This company has all the gimmicks to screw the public,  Do check-in on line and save yourself 55 Euros and try to print that your check-in was a done deal.